# Unable to send push notification to live iOS app on AppStore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have uploaded my app to iTunesConnect and is available on AppStore now. When I try to push notification to live devices with production device tokens and production server certificates, the client is not receiving the pushes.

I suspect their can be issue with server APNS certificates. It worked well on development environment with development certificates and device tokens.

When I check my apple developer member profile, App Ids. I see there are two green dots for my app; push notification enabled for development and production.

How can I fix the problem? Can I generate new certificates for production and revoke an existing one?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some more information, what kind of response u got after sending push notification from APN server ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the server code has "Production" mode enabled for push messages,i think the code is still pointing to "Sandbox" environment.

You can test Production push notifications (Production mode) via Ad-Hoc provisioning profile.If you are getting messages then the Production mode is enabled otherwise you need to set the Production mode on your web server.

Comment: Production mode with production device token and production certificates are used on server.

Comment: Have you tested the app with  Ad-Hoc provisioning profile and push messages are working?

Comment: No, I haven't tested that. I have tested on development environment only.

Comment: Please test using that .If you don't know how to do then you can follow [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: When I create the Ad hoc and install on a registered device, will the production certificates APNS work on that or Sandbox one, which are used in TestFlight?

Comment: When you use Ad hoc,production certificates along with Production mode will work.